# Viewing Ray Dashboard on AWS SageMaker (currently it's blank)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, ray

I am trying to use ray on AWS SageMaker in a Jupyter Notebook.

The dashboard GUI not working for me, as it displays a blank page (rendered in browser)

The Ray framework seems to run perhaps needs some debugging / evaluation.

My goal is to access the dashboard feature. Note that I installed Ray with

> pip install ray[dashboard]

When `ray.init()` is called, I got the message about accessing the dashboard at `localhost:8265`, which is equivalent to `https://<aws-notebook-instance>/proxy/8265/` on AWS:

```py
ray.init(
    num_cpus = num_cpus, 
    num_gpus = num_gpus,
    ignore_reinit_error = True, 
    include_webui = None, 
    webui_host = 'localhost'
)
```

After some testing, it seemed the dashboard API is there and responsive, but the browser displays only a blank page with embedded Javascript & CSS objects (if viewed in dev mode).

Looking in a GitHub repo, I tested actual API calls under the `/api/` path - and some of those return data in a raw format, through the browser didn't do what I intended.

All I could think of is maybe some of the app framework or dependencies weren't installed on the host?

My environment info can be found here: https://pastebin.com/tsR0NB5t

Comment: i see the URL for the dashboard wasn't displayed properly - its https://MYNOTEBOOKINSTANCENAME.notebook.us-east-1.sagemaker.aws/proxy/8265/